# Error: File cannot be found. Check the path in 'file' in R

Tags: r, readxl

I am trying to use moimport() in R to import the file in R

```
datas <- read.xlsx("pathfile.xlsx",sheetName = 1)

datas
datatype <- c(rep("amino",9),rep("str",41))
coding <- c(rep("3let",9),rep("integer",41))

    
exfile <- "home/errors.xlsx"
dat <- moimport(datas,nummtd=1,keepmtd = TRUE,molecular=datatype,coding =coding)
```

but when I execute it, getting this following error.

```
Error: File cannot be found. Check the path in 'file'.
```

Comment: check your current working directory with `getwd()`, it is likely you are not in the same directory as the file; alternatively, use the relative or path in the call, as in `"/path/to/pathfile.xlsx"`.

Comment: Assuming `moimport` is from `MLMOI`, the function expects a string path to the file you want to read, and right now you are passing in `datas` which is a data.frame. Did you mean to pass in `exfile` as the first parameter?

Comment: Yes moimport is from the MLMOI package and I am trying to read from the same directory but still it's showing the same error :(